# How convert a progression of minutes in date in Python

Tags: python, analysis

I open the .CSV file and load it in a dataframe. The first column is `'TIME [minutes]'`. Every 30 minutes I have the second column `'Temperature'...` one row every 30 minutes for a full year!

So I start with `0`, than `30`, then `60` ... and finish with `527010`.
Now I have to convert this minutes to a specific date (starting from `1-01-2019` and ending with `12-31-2019`) so I can aggregate and analyze the data for week, month, days, etc.

Comment: The [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module lets you do arithmetic with time, such as for example adding increments of 30 minutes to a starting date & time. You might want to contemplate whether you want your program to be timezone-aware or not before you start coding. Questions to consider: is the starting date and time in a particular timezone? Is every other time in the *same* TZ? Do you want a leap second to be accounted for or not? Leap day? Daylight savings time?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: My problem is more easy for the moment(my trainer is not so collaborative and he didn't explain me better the datetime module and he didn't help me to understand what can I do...) I don't have to consider Time Zone, or leap day (2019 wasn't)...I need only to convert in a date. I think that I can add another column in the dataframe and start from a specific date (in this case 1-1-2019  00:00:00) and finish at the end of the rows. If you have also some free video where i can learn more about this module, I would appreciate very much.

Comment: Piece of unrelated advice: immediately pivoting to blaming your teacher is not a good habit. For your own sake.

Comment: In a normal situation I would agree with you...anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may try `pd.to_timedelta(values, unit='m')` and add some start date. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=dict(
        minutes=np.arange(10)*30,
        temp=np.random.normal(size=10),
    ))

origin = pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01')

df['t'] = origin + pd.to_timedelta(df['minutes'], unit='m')
df.set_index('t')

Out[ ]:
                     minutes      temp
t                                     
2019-01-01 00:00:00        0  0.072195
2019-01-01 00:30:00       30 -1.744107
2019-01-01 01:00:00       60  0.847826
2019-01-01 01:30:00       90 -1.434030
2019-01-01 02:00:00      120  1.831201
2019-01-01 02:30:00      150 -0.198310
2019-01-01 03:00:00      180  1.430119
2019-01-01 03:30:00      210  0.104412
2019-01-01 04:00:00      240  1.786200
2019-01-01 04:30:00      270  0.776551
```

Note: the above is using naive timestamps. If you need to do your work in a timezone-aware setting, just modify your origin as such. Here is another example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=dict(
        minutes=np.arange(10) * 30,
        temp=np.random.normal(size=10),
    ))

origin = pd.Timestamp('2019-03-09 23:15:00', tz='America/Los_Angeles')

df.assign(date=origin + pd.to_timedelta(df['minutes'], unit='m')).set_index('date')

Out[ ]:
                           minutes      temp
date                                        
2019-03-09 23:15:00-08:00        0  1.467329
2019-03-09 23:45:00-08:00       30 -0.645978
2019-03-10 00:15:00-08:00       60 -0.673867
2019-03-10 00:45:00-08:00       90 -0.133427
2019-03-10 01:15:00-08:00      120 -0.888888
2019-03-10 01:45:00-08:00      150 -0.626973
2019-03-10 03:15:00-07:00      180  1.613762
2019-03-10 03:45:00-07:00      210  0.314589
2019-03-10 04:15:00-07:00      240 -0.100282
2019-03-10 04:45:00-07:00      270  0.447192
```

Notice how it switches from `PST` to `PDT` as per the rules of that timezone.

Comment: Thanks Pierre D!! Works...I can continue with my analysis...have a great day!